# footfullcite in block doesn't show the reference as I wanted

Tags: beamer

I am making a academic presentation. I want to put the reference in the block.

[image]

But I want to put the reference number directly after word "Theorem". so I tried

[image]

The reference showed up right in the block which is really terrible. It seems that the block affects the footcite. How do I solve it?

Comment: Please post a small, but compilable test document as text and not as image

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around the problem like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{This is a citation\footnote[frame]{\fullcite{knuth:ct}}.}
  content...
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{References}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked! There is only one thing different from yours. I have a round bracket for the reference at the bottom even I copied yours, but it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: There is one more thing I would like to ask you. How can I change the size of the reference at bottom using the format you provided. Where should I add {size=\tiny}?

Comment: @STUDENT If you have a new question, use the "Ask Question" button on the top right and show a small test document.